# Insert order to MongoDB from localStorage

Tags: javascript, angular, mongodb

Basically, I want to take the products from local storage and insert them to mongoDB.

My backend works perfectly.
Order Schema :

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let Order = new Schema ({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    firstName: {type: String},
    lastName: {type: String},
    email:  {type: String},
    phone: {type: Number},
    createdAt:  {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    address: {type: String},
    productName: {type: String},
    productDesc: {type: String},
    productQuantity: {type: Number},
    productPrice:{type: Number},
    totalPrice:{type: Number},

    
},
{
    collection: 'orders'
}
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Order', Order);
```

Order routing:

```js
//post order
orderRouter.route('/').post((req, res) =>{
    const order = new Order({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        email: req.body.email,
        firstName:req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        email: req.body.email,
        phone: req.body.phone,
        address: req.body.address,
        productName: req.body.productName,
        productDesc: req.body.productDesc,
        productQuantity: req.body.productQuantity,
        productPrice:req.body.productPrice,
        totalPrice:req.body.totalPrice,
    });
    order.save()
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        return res.status(200).json({
            message: "Order was Created",
            
            order: {
                _id: order._id,
                
                firstName:order.firstName,
                lastName: order.lastName,
                email: order.email,
                phone: order.phone,
                address: order.address,
                createdAt: new Date,
                productName: order.productName,
                productDesc: order.productName,
                productQuantity: order.productQuantity,
                productPrice: order.productPrice,
                totalPrice: order.totalPrice
            }
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            error:err
        });
    });

});
```

products are saved in local storage:
[image]

CheckoutForm.HTML(only the cart fields):

```html
          <div class="col-md-4 order-md-2 mb-4">
            
            <h4 class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-3">
                
              <span class="text-muted">Your cart</span>
              <span class="badge badge-secondary badge-pill">{{ productService.itemCount()}}</span>
            </h4>
            <ul class="list-group mb-1">
              <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed"  *ngFor = "let prod of productAddedToCart;">
                <div class = form-group>
                    
                  <h6 class="my-0" formControlName = "productName" ngDefaultControl name = "productName" #productName>{{prod.product_Name}}</h6>
                  
                  
                  <small class="text-muted" formControlName = "productQuantity" ngDefaultControl>Quantity: {{prod.product_Quantity}}</small><br>
                </div>
                <div class = "form-group">
                <span class="text-muted" formControlName = "productPrice" ngDefaultControl>{{prod.product_Price * prod.product_Quantity | currency: '$'}}</span>
            </div>
            </li>
            <div class = "form-group">
              <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between">
                  <strong><span>Total (USD)</span></strong>
                <strong formcontrolName = "totalPrice" ngDefaultControl>{{allTotal | currency: '$' }}</strong>
              </li>
            </div>
            </ul>
```

CheckoutForm.TS:

```js
constructor(private orderService:OrderService,private productService: ProductService, private fb: FormBuilder, private connectionService: ConnectionService, private router: Router) {
    this.createForm();
   
   }


  createForm(){
    this.checkOutForm = this.fb.group({
      firstName : [null, Validators.required],
      lastName : [null, Validators.required],
      phone : [null, Validators.required],
      email : [null, Validators.required],
      address : [null, Validators.required],
      country: [null, Validators.required],
      city : [null, Validators.required],
      nameOnCard : [null, Validators.required],
      creditCardNumber: [null, Validators.required],
      exp: [null, Validators.required],
      cvv: [null, Validators.required],
      message: [''],
      contactFormCopy: [''],
      productName: [Validators.required],
      ProductDesc: [Validators.required],
      productQuantity: [Validators.required],
      productPrice: [Validators.required],
      totalPrice: [Validators.required]

  });
}

onSubmit() {
  this.connectionService.sendReceipt(this.checkOutForm.value).subscribe(() => {
    alert('Your order has been received.');
    this.orderService.CreateOrder(this.checkOutForm.value).subscribe((data:Order) => {
      this.order = data
      console.log(this.order);
    });
    this.checkOutForm.reset();
    this.disabledSubmitButton = true;
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
    localStorage.removeItem('product');
    localStorage.removeItem('cartItemCount');
  }, error => {
    console.log('Error', error);
  });
}
```

In MongoDB:

[image]

As you can see, only fields with 'Input' and 'formControlName' are saved in the database, 
and I understand that 'formContolName' must be inside an 'Input' field.

So my question is, how do I take the product details from local storage and assign them to their 
proper fields in the HTML file?

Appreciated!

Comment: You need to have a backend, or some intermediary, is not safe to send information directly from the browser to a database

Comment: I have a backend that works, just didnt want to post too much :)